# Need to login before going to a new page

Tags: ruby, selenium, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm currently using Ruby and Capybara and writing tests. I have a login page already done and it works fine. I'm trying to create a separate test where I want it to already login before going to that page.

My login Code:

```
class LoginPage < SitePrism::Page
    set_url '/'
    element :username_field, '#username'
    element :password_field, '#password'
    element :login_button, '#login_button'
   
  
    def login()
        username_field.send_keys 'Cow'
        password_field.send_keys 'dogs'
        login_button.click
    end
    
    def load_and_login(*args)
        self.load
        login(*args)
        self
    end
end
```

This is my new page. Where I want it to login prior to going to this page.

```
describe login do
    before(:each) do
        home = LoginPage.new
        home.load
        home.login
    end
end

class newPage < SitePrism::Page
    include RSpec::Matchers
    include Capybara::RSpecMatchers
  
    set_url '/new'
  
end
```

This is the error that I"m getting:

```
Failure/Error: Dir['./pages/**/*.rb'].sort.each { |f| require f }

NameError:
  undefined local variable or method `login' for main:Object
```

Comment: What authentication library are you using? Depending on what you're using you'll probably want to use that libraries built-in test helpers to shortcut actually logging in on all tests other than those specifically testing the login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`describe login do` -- looks like problem here

Change it to `describe '#login' do`

Comment: Also might need RSpec.describe dependent on your use context